# how to run/execute Job on multiple nodes of worker server from remote server (master server) with spring batch integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-batch-integration

We have existing Spring Batch Application, that we want to make scalable to run on multiple nodes.

For example, I would like to run a job on different worker servers. In the case, where I have a Job A and a Job B, run Job A on a instance of the worker server and Job B in another instance of the worker server.

In the spring batch integration doc I find an explanation on the remote partitioning of setps. However I can't figure out how we can start several nodes of a worker server from the master server.

If you can give me some indication of the way that I can follow.
Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is outside the scope of Spring Batch. Consider Spring Cloud Data Flow.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow

Comment: thank you for your answer, 
Would you have an example to follow to advise me please?

Comment: It looks like there is a batch sample on the project page https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow#samples; you should also refer to the reference documentation.

Comment: What do you think about spring lightmin? i found this example on github https://github.com/tuxdevelop/spring-batch-lightmin

Comment: I am not familiar with it.